# Combining two cells in excel but keeping the font

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula

I am trying to merge two cells into one multiline cell. The first cell consists of an address, the second cell holds a number that gets converted into a barcode by using a special font.

The content of the second cell should keep the font that is assigned to it(barcode font), after merging it with the first cell.

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

UPDATE:

Here is my working solution

```
Sub barcode()
Dim i As Integer
With Worksheets("sheet4")
    For i = 2 To 19539
        With .Cells(i, "J")
            .Value = .Offset(0, -2).Value2 & Chr(10) & .Offset(0, -1).Value2
            .Characters(Start:=Len(.Offset(0, -2).Value2) + 2, _
                        Length:=Len(.Offset(0, -1).Value2)).Font.Name = .Offset(0, -1).Font.Name
        End With
    Next i
End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Manipulate the .Characters property.

```
With Worksheets("sheet4")
    With .Cells(6, "F")
        .Value = .Offset(0, -2).Value2 & Chr(10) & .Offset(0, -1).Value2
        .Characters(Start:=Len(.Offset(0, -2).Value2) + 1, _
                    Length:=Len(.Offset(0, -1).Value2)).Font.Name = .Offset(0, -1).Font.Name
    End With
End With
```

[image]

Comment: Great, definately the right answer! Now I have about 20,000 rows, how can I make this variable to work with several lines at once?

Comment: Each combination pair of cells will have to be dealt with individually. Either `for each x in ... next x` or `for i=2 to ... Next i`.

Comment: Actually im not very familiar with VBA scripting. Would you mind updating your original answer with the foreach loop applied?

Comment: Ok, got it working by myself - updated my question accordingly